# Convergent Sequences and limits

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_1 > 0$ and

$ x_{n+1} = 1/2 (x_n + 2/x_n)= x^2n+2/2x_n, n\geq1.$

Does $\{x_{n+1}\}$ converge? If so, find its limit.

Hint: Prove first that if $a, b \geq 0$ ,then $ 2ab \leq a^2 + b^2. $

I don't see how the hint is suppose to help.

Comment: Try formatting your expressions to avoid ambiguity, in particular your fractions.

Comment: Your equality does not make sense. Please edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose it converges, then both ${x_n}$ and ${x_{n+1}}$ approach the same limit, say $x$. This means (if I deciphered your expression correctly)
$$x = \frac{1}{2}\left( {x + \frac{2}{x}} \right)$$
or
$$2{x^2} = {x^2} + 2$$
so
$$x =  \pm \sqrt 2.$$
Since all terms are positive, the limit must be $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: We can prove that $x_2\geq x_3\geq\ldots\geq\sqrt{2}$, so the sequence converges.